# How to Hide TEXTBOX in GridView with TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my Coding

I would like to hide "txtQtyOrder10" in if condition after clicking on SEARCH Button. when I'm trying to access from part.aspx.cs file it's show up error msg.

I don't have idea how can I get access to the text fields for hide.

Here is some coding for refer what i'm trying to do.

Any help will be appreciate.

## part.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOutput" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   BackColor="Transparent" AllowSorting="True"
   BorderColor="Navy" BorderWidth="2px" GridLines="None" OnSorting="OnSort" 
   OnRowCreated="OnRowCreated"
   OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvOutputSelectedIndexChanging" CellPadding="2" 
   DataKeyNames="LineID"
   AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50" OnPageIndexChanging="gvOutput_PageIndexChanging" 
   OnDataBound="OnDataBound" SelectedIndex="1">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
           <HeaderTemplate>
               <input id="chkAll" onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" 
               runat="server" type="checkbox" />
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" 
               Checked='<%# Eval("[Select]") %>'/>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="PROD80" HeaderText="Number">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPart" runat="server" CommandName="Select" 
               Text='<%# Bind("PROD80") %>'></asp:LinkButton>    
           </ItemTemplate>
           <ControlStyle CssClass="grid" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="DESC80" HeaderText="Description" 
          SortExpression="DESC80" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="VEND80" HeaderText="Vendor" 
          SortExpression="VEND80" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="BUYE80" HeaderText="Planner" 
          SortExpression="BUYE80" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="PMIUM" HeaderText="UOM" 
          SortExpression="PMIUM" />

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order 10">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtQtyOrder10" runat="server" 
               Text=<%#Bind("QTYORDER10")%> onfocus="this.select()" 
               CssClass="textbox" Height="13px" Width="60px" />
               <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbeQty10" runat="server" 
                   TargetControlID="txtQtyOrder10" FilterType="Numbers">
               </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order 50">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtQtyOrder50" runat="server" 
               Text=<%#Bind("QTYORDER50")%> onfocus="this.select()" 
               CssClass="textbox" Height="13px" Width="60px" />
               <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbeQty50" runat="server" 
                   TargetControlID="txtQtyOrder50" FilterType="Numbers">
               </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>                                       
   </Columns>
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="gvOutputHeader" />
   <RowStyle ForeColor="Navy" Height="15px" Font-Size="Small" />
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="White" />
   <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
</asp:GridView>
```

## part.aspx.cs

```
 protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //if user clicks on 'Below X Weeks' or 'Below X Weeks w/o PO', 
        //they must enter  a value in txt box.
        if ((!rdBelowXWeeks.Checked || txtWeek.Text != string.Empty) &&     
           (!rdBelowXWeeksWPO.Checked || txtWeek.Text != string.Empty))
    {
        try
        {
            //clear data of a previous search 
            ClearResultsScreen();
            ClearDetailsScreen();

            //get radio button value selected by user (default is all)
            if (rdAll.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdAll.Value;
            else if (rdBelowTrigger.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdBelowTrigger.Value;
            else if (rdAboveTrigger.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdAboveTrigger.Value;
            else if (rdBelowSafety.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdBelowSafety.Value;
            else if (rdBelowXWeeksWPO.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdBelowXWeeksWPO.Value




     //*****WOULD LIKE TO HIDE from HERE *************//







        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblErrMessage.Text = "ERROR: Number of weeks is required";
        lblErrMessage.Visible = true;
    }

}//end cmdSearch_Click
```

Comment: You dont can just set txtQtyOrder10.visible = false; in code behind?

Comment: PiLHA @ it's appears error message that " txtQtyOrder10 does not exist in the current content. "

Comment: Then try to use: 
TextBox txtQtyOrder10 = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtQtyOrder10"); or
TextBox txtQtyOrder10 = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txtQtyOrder10");
and then repeat my first comment command.

Comment: PiLAH @ error msg :- "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement"

Comment: How the textbox is inside a grid, only you could see that by the Rowdataboun or any events from the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you can hide or show controls inside a grid In the rowDataBound or any grid event.

Try this code below:

```
    protected void gvOutput_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

            //get radio button value selected by user (default is all)
            if (rdAll.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdAll.Value;
            else if (rdBelowTrigger.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdBelowTrigger.Value;
            else if (rdAboveTrigger.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdAboveTrigger.Value;
            else if (rdBelowSafety.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdBelowSafety.Value;
            else if (rdBelowXWeeksWPO.Checked)
                search.SearchType = rdBelowXWeeksWPO.Value

              //Hide the Textbox
               TextBox txtQtyOrder10 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtQtyOrder10");
               txtQtyOrder10.Visible = false;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingComponent.Instance.LogMessage(bo.Enums.LoggingType.Error, DateTime.Now, ex.Message, bo.Enums.Module.Order, "gvProductsAdded_RowDataBound", bo.Enums.ApplicationLevel.FrontEnd, "Error en los Productos a Despachar");
            DisplayMessage(GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "UnknowError").ToString(), bo.Enums.MessageType.Error);
        }


    }
```

I hope that help you.

Cheers